# Typescript error, Property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have defined the type and passed the `reminderInfo` object:

```
type Props = {

  reminderInfo?: {
    reminderButtonText?: string | undefined;
    reminderUrl?: string | undefined;
  };
};
const component: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({
  reminderInfo,
}) => {
```

When I try and destructure in my component:

```
  const onPress = () => {
    const { reminderUrl } = reminderInfo;
```

It gives me the error:

> Property 'reminderUrl' does not exist on type '{ reminderButtonText?: string | undefined; reminderUrl?: string | undefined; } | undefined'

Comment: `reminderInfo` is optional and therefore could be `undefined`. And destructuring of an `undefined` object is not possible. Idea: provide a default value for `reminderInfo`, like empty strings for its properties and remove the optional operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `reminderInfo` as an optional property in Props, reminderInfo could be undefined. When you deconstruct like

`const { reminderUrl } = reminderInfo;`

TypeScript complains because it's not certain that reminderInfo actually exists.

You can use the folloing code to fix the problem:

```
const onPress = () => {
  if (reminderInfo) {
    const { reminderUrl } = reminderInfo;
    // Do something
  }
};
```

Comment: still gives me, Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: @Bomber ok! seem that you need to check `reminderUrl` exist before using it because its type is `string | undefined`. Use the following to take a try:

```const reminderUrl = reminderInfo?.reminderUrl;
if (reminderUrl) {
    // Do something
}```